# Softkeyboard is shown only on calling method from button click

Tags: android-softkeyboard, android-button

I am programatically showing the soft keyboard when a layout is loaded on a button click.
I am showing the softkeyboard only when the textfield has focus. It works fine. But when I call the same method at another place in the code(not a button click) then the soft keyboard does not show up. Below is my code. Please point out where I went wrong.

```
public void showNewView() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    isRegisterScreen = true;
    final EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.label1);
    final EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.label2);

    final InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    text1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                inputManager.showSoftInput(labelText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            }else{
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(text1.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });

    text2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                inputManager.showSoftInput(text2, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            }else{
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(phoneText.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
    });

    text1.requestFocus();
```

}

Comment: It seems that your text1 can not get focus, maybe because it's parent view doesn't have it. Try to understand which view has focus at this time.

Comment: @barn.gumbl the text view gets the focus, but the soft-keyboard is not shown when calling the same method by clicking 'ok' on a message box